If in a column is a followup number than count this followup numbers otherwise just count the week
Hello I tried to write a program to count the custom weeks as days. I have a column with custom weeks but if there's a followup number, than it should count these numbers.
The table are the weeks which needs to be counted (the followup weeks).
The code should be:
If next number is a followup number, then count the followup weeks. Otherwise if it's 1 week than outcome is 1.
The numbers should be converted to a date.
See example below.
The yellow cell is the custom date.


So, basically, input is a week number (30 as example) and then you need to count how many consecutive numbers are in your table, starting at 30 (30,, 31, 32 in your image), multiply this count by 7 and then sum up this result to enddate, correct?

Yes, the date + the consecutive weeks'. But it could be any consecutive weeks. So another example would be that week 20 till 25 are consecutive weeks. Then the sum must be, '7d * the remaining weeks of the consecutive colum'. If the enddate is in week 20 than the output must be the 'enddate + 5 w (35d)'. If the enddate is in week 21 than it would be the 'enddate + 4w (28d)'.

There may be other ways to do this, but I think it's reasonable to use a lambda to check if a week number follows on from the previous week:
=LET(Date,A2,
     startWeek,B2,
     endWeek,REDUCE(startWeek-1,Table1[Week],LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=a+1,a+1,a))),
     Date+7*(endWeek-startWeek+1))



Thank you for your reaction.
But if i want to add a duration between a begindate and enddate.
Let's say (start)date (A2) = 8/july/2024 and the let's say, enddate = 5/augustus/2024.
The som need to be: Som(enddate - startdate + "missing days in the holiday")
